# Azure Automation - Why can't I add a PowerShell Runbook on a Graphical PowerShell Workflow Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I've just started using **Azure Automation**, and I wanted to use the *Graphical Workflow* so I could make a flow of *Runbooks*. I created a *PowerShellWorkflow Runbook* and a *Powershell Runbook*.

I can add the *Powershell Runbook* to the canvas but not the *PowerShellWorkflow Runbook*, it doesn't even show in the Runbook menu. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation on what can you can include in the Graphical runbooks based on what type of Graphical runbook core type you've created.

From the docs at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-graphical-authoring-intro

> These runbooks can be added to the canvas to be used as child runbooks. Only runbooks of the same core type as the runbook being edited are shown; for Graphical runbooks only PowerShell-based runbooks are shown, while for Graphical PowerShell Workflow runbooks only PowerShell-Workflow-based runbooks are shown.